# Azure Management Portal security

Tags: azure

With one login account, someone is able to log into the Azure Management Portal and stop, delete and change all of the services that we are running.  Additionally, there doesn't seem to be any way for us to 'backup' and 'restore' in the case of something like this occurring.

Is there a way to mitigate against a risk like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of today, there's no `Role Based Access Control` thing for Windows Azure Portal (or any other services for that matter). If somebody has access to portal, they would have access to all features and functionality available there (including deletes). Furthermore, portal does not offer anything like "backup" your existing configuration. You would need to do this on your own. I'm not sure if contacting support would provide some help if something bad goes with your subscription. You may want to explore that.

I guess the only way to mitigate against a risk like this would be to be careful in granting access to the portal (I know, its quite lame response :)).

Comment: It's clearly a huge risk to have our entire production environment (consisting of at least 10-15 different services) in this situation.  I wonder if they would be able to provide support in this area.  I am one of two people with access to the portal for this very reason... I would really like to get others involved, but I just can't risk it!

Comment: I could not agree more. One click of a button and you're toast. Let's hope something comes up very soon.

Answer (score 2):

Role-based access control has been announced last Wednesday (September 10th) for the Azure Preview Portal. Custom roles will be coming soon, as well:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/role-based-access-control-in-azure-preview-portal/

Answer (score 1):

There is no backup as such, apart from from for SQL Azure.

You can achieve a similar goal by scripting all your deployment and configuration using the Azure management API etc. You can do anything that way that you can via the portal (more actually).

Things like cloud service packages and config are bundled into packages, which are sort of like a backup.

VHDs can be stored locally. But blob and table data could be a problem since you might have vast amounts of it. However, you cannot modify blobs in the portal so they are a bit safer. You could delete the whole storage account though...

You could limit the scope of damage by using multiple subscriptions with e.g. a single service in each, and with storage in separate subscriptions etc.

And obviously you should change account passwords often and whenever anyone leaves your business.

Finally, when all else fails, at least you have the operation logs for non-repudiation.